# Python - How to PYTHONPATH with a complex directory structure?

Tags: python, pythonpath, python-import

Consider the following file\directory structure:

```
project\
|  django_project\
|  |  __init__.py
|  |  django_app1\
|  |  |  __init__.py
|  |  |  utils\
|  |  |  |  __init__.py
|  |  |  |  bar1.py
|  |  |  |  ...
|  |  |  ...
|  |  django_app2\
|  |  |  __init__.py
|  |  |  bar2.py
|  |  |  ...
|  |  ...
|  scripts\
|  |  __init__.py
|  |  foo.py
|  |  ...
```

How should I use **sys.path.append** in **foo.py** so that I could use **bar1.py** and **bar2.py**?
How would the **import** look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **relative paths** would be much more desirable for portability reasons.

At the top of your `foo.py` script add the following:

```
import os, sys
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), os.pardir)
sys.path.append(PROJECT_ROOT)

# Now you can import from the django_project package
from django_project.django_app1.utils import bar1
from django_project.django_app2 import bar2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/absolute/whatever/project/django_project/django_app1')
sys.path.append('/absolute/whatever/project/django_project/django_app2')
```

Though you need to evaluate whether you want to have both in your path -- in case there are competing module names in both. It might make sense to only have up to `django_project` in your path, and call `django_app1/bar1.py` when you need it and `import django_app2.bar2.whatever` when you need it.